# Subfigures are not bottom aligned

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to bottom align two `pgfplots` figures (both have `width=95\textwidth` set) and also have a bounding box drawn. The relevant code that sets up the two `subfigure`s:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \input{./texfig/FN_plot}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \input{./texfig/FN_plot_hot}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{FN plot. Protrusion height $h=\SI{20}{nm}$. Real (apex) $\beta = 11.8$. On the left, $T_{\text{ambient}} = \SI{300}{K}$ and on the right $T_{\text{ambient}} = \SI{800}{K}$.}
    \label{fig:FN_plot}
\end{figure}
```

And the result is:

[image].

Why are they not bottom aligned? Clearly, the bounding boxes are not overlapping. By reducing the width of the figures, I can get them to align, but then there's too much white space between them. Any ideas?

EDIT: Removed all the irrelevant stuff and here are the `.tex` files:

`FN_plot.tex`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2, vertical sep=1.3cm}]

    \nextgroupplot[
        width=0.8\linewidth,
        xmin = 0.00125, xmax = 0.00135,
        ymin =-24.15, ymax = -23.85,
        ]   

    \nextgroupplot[
        width=0.95\textwidth,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 0.05,
        ymin =-200, ymax = -20,
        ytick = {-20,-60,...,-220},
        xtick = {0,0.01,...,0.04},
        xlabel={$1/E$ $\left[(\si{MV/m})^{-1}\right]$},
        ylabel={$\ln{(I/E^2)}$ $\left[\si{A.m^2.MV^{-2}}\right]$},
        legend pos = north east,
        legend cell align = left,
        legend style = {draw=none,fill=none}]

    \end{groupplot}


    \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and

`FN_plot_hot.tex`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Inf=inf;}]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.95\textwidth,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 0.05,
        ymin =-200, ymax = -20,
        ytick = {-20,-60,...,-220},
        xtick = {0,0.01,...,0.04},
        xlabel={$1/E$ $\left[(\si{MV/m})^{-1}\right]$},
        %ylabel={$\ln{(I/E^2)}$ $\left[\si{A.m^2.MV^{-2}}\right]$},
        yticklabels={,,},
        legend pos = north east,
        legend cell align = left,
        legend style = {draw=none,fill=none}]

    \end{axis}

    \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: What does `./texfig/FN_plot.tex` and `./texfig/FN_plot_hot.tex` look like? They seem to be the offenders.

Comment: @Werner removed all irrelevant stuff and added the .tex files.

Comment: I've debugged that without using `\input` and just copying the contents of the file, this alignment issue resolves. But I need to use `\input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupplot` to plot all three of them in a go. Just use

```
\nextgroupplot[hide axis]%2
```

for the second plot so that it is not plotted. Here is a sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},
height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small]
\nextgroupplot%1
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
\nextgroupplot[hide axis]%2
%\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
\nextgroupplot%3
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
\nextgroupplot%4
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{FN plot. Protrusion height $h=\SI{20}{nm}$. Real (apex) $\beta = 11.8$. On the left, $T_{\text{ambient}} = \SI{300}{K}$ and on the right $T_{\text{ambient}} = \SI{800}{K}$.}
    \label{fig:FN_plot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With your approach it becomes  (this works with `\input` also)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2},
height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small]
\nextgroupplot%1
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
\nextgroupplot%2
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
\begin{axis}[height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
    \caption{FN plot. Protrusion height $h=\SI{20}{nm}$. Real (apex) $\beta = 11.8$. On the left, $T_{\text{ambient}} = \SI{300}{K}$ and on the right $T_{\text{ambient}} = \SI{800}{K}$.}
    \label{fig:FN_plot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And with your files, I get this

[image]